# How to use sscanf with loops correctly with ill-formatted input?

Tags: c, stdin

I'm trying to read from stdin the commands for a stack data structure, the valid command are "push [number]" and "pop", here's my code:

```
while(getline(&input, &len, stdin) > 0){
while ((n = sscanf(input,"%64s%d%n",cmd,&num,&offset)) > 0){
    if (n == 1){
        if (!strcmp("pop",cmd)){
            pop(&head);
        } else if (!strcmp("push",cmd)){
            //Doing something
        } else if (isNumeric(cmd) && need_num){
            push(&head, num);
        } else{
            //error
        }
    }
    else if (n == 2){
        if (!strcmp("push",cmd)){
            push(&head, num);
        } else {
            //error
        }
    }
    else {
        //error
    }
    input += offset;
}
}
```

This Program has many flaws, of course, since I'm not familiar with sscanf with loops. The first problem is that if I read in a series of commands in a line such as:

```
push 1 push 2 pop  push 3
```

It will actually cause error, since there's number following push but no number after pop, in this way, this line of code is wrong for "pop" command:

```
input += offset;
```

But I don't know how to fix that.
The other problem is that if I suppose split a "push [number]" command into 2 lines is acceptable:

```
push 5 pop push
4
```

I don't know if there's any easier way other than what I did to decide whether the line end up with push and the following line start with a number:

```
else if (!strcmp("push",cmd)){
        //Doing something
    } else if (isNumeric(cmd) && need_num){
        push(&head, num);
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Any reason why you want to take your input the way you are doing? You can easily split your input to two parts - a) Use sscanf to read what the command is and b) if command is "push" use scanf to read a number otherwise just pop

Comment: I get the idea, however, given the wacky function I've done with, what could be done to make it work? Thank you!

Comment: (don't forget to set `offset=0;` between the call to `getline` and your `while` loop with `sscanf`). Otherwise, there are no glaring issues with your `sscanf` or `if` or `offset` logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well there were not any glaring errors in your use, but there were a number of subtle errors that caused you problems.

The primary problem you were faced with was taking only a single offset after both the string and integer were converted. In the case of `"pop"`, a *matching failure* occurs with `%d` **before** you ever reach `%n` in your *format string* causing `n` to remain unset (retaining the last set value -- causing your increment of `offset` to be too large in that case)

Instead, you need to employ two such checks in your format string, e.g.:

```
    while ((rtn = sscanf (input, "%63s %n%d %n", 
                            cmd, &off1, &num, &off2)) > 0) {
```

That way if `"pop"` is read, you have a proper offset in `off1` and if `"push num"` is read, you have the proper offset in `off2`. (the additional whitespace before each `%n` is optional (but suggested). With both `%s` and `%d` leading whitespace is consumed -- but best to get in the habit of accounting for it, as `%[...]` or `%c` do not consume leading whitepace.

Putting it together in a short example, you could do something similar to the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXCMD 64   /* max characters for command */

int main (void) {

    char *buf = NULL;   /* buffer for getline */
    size_t n = 0;       /* alloc size (0 getline decides) */
    ssize_t nchr = 0;   /* getline returns (no. of chars read */

    while ((nchr = getline (&buf, &n, stdin)) > 0) {    /* read each line */
        char cmd[MAXCMD] = "",  /* buffer for command */
            *input = buf;       /* pointer to advance */
        int num = 0,            /* number to push */
            off1 = 0,           /* offset if single conversion */
            off2 = 0,           /* offset if double conversion */
            rtn = 0;            /* sscanf return */
        while ((rtn = sscanf (input, "%63s %n%d %n", 
                                cmd, &off1, &num, &off2)) > 0) {
            switch (rtn) {      /* switch on sscanf return */
                case 1:         /* handle "pop" case */
                    if (strcmp (cmd, "pop") == 0) {
                        printf ("pop\n");
                        input += off1;  /* set offset based on off1 */
                    }
                    else
                        fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid single cmd '%s'.\n",
                                        cmd);
                    break;
                case 2:         /* handle "push num" case */
                    if (strcmp (cmd, "push") == 0) {
                        printf ("push %d\n", num);
                        input += off2;  /* set offset based on off2 */
                    }
                    else
                        fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid single cmd '%s'.\n",
                                cmd);
                    break;
                default:
                    fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid input.\n");
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
    free (buf);     /* free memory allocated by getline */

    return 0;
}
```

(**note:** I have used a `switch()` statement, but you are free to use `if, else if, else` if you prefer)

**Example Use/Output**

Validation cases:

```
$ echo "pop pop push 1 push 2 pop push 3 pop" | ./bin/sscanfpushpop
pop
pop
push 1
push 2
pop
push 3
pop

$ echo "push 5 pop push 6 push 7 pop push 8" | ./bin/sscanfpushpop
push 5
pop
push 6
push 7
pop
push 8
```

Look things over and let me know if you have any further questions.

Comment: Thanks! That's very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

You could split your line with `" "` as delimiter in a `char **` or a `char tab[][]` if the size is constant.

Then you would check if your `tab[i]` is a number and then use it as you want or a command that, if followed `(tab[i+1])` by a number, would be « push », else « pop ».